# Calling a method from a created instance

Tags: c#, oop, xna

First post so hi! (please correct me if I use some term wrong)

I've got a class Screen in which I create an instance of another class named Player (let's call this instance Player). Now, in Screen I have a method called ResetHUD which I would like to call from Player.

How would I do that? The only code inside ResetHUD is 1 line which sets a variable to another variable. As far as I know I can use EventHandler (but since ResetHUD doesn't need any arguments I'm thinking that I'm using that wrong) or delegates (which I have no idea how to use).

Help is appreciated!

Comment: please put your code in Q, if you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a containment relationship... the Screen object contains one (or more?) Player objects.

When Screen creates Player, it can set a property on Player indicating the parent (creating) Screen object.

```
class Player
{
    private Screen parentScreen;

    public Player(Screen parentScreen) { this.parentScreen = parentScreen; }

    public MyMethodThatHasToCallScreensMethod()
    {
        parentScreen.ResetHUD();
    }
}


class Screen
{
    public Player CreatePlayer()
    {
        return new Player(this);
    }
}
```

You can also use events (events by the way can have parameters, or not, depending on what you need).

This is my favorite tutorial on events and delegates in C#.  Starts simple and builds on each step.

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html

Comment: The screen contains 1 or more players, yes.

I thought about passing it as an argument but it seems like it'd be bad practice or just plain bad to do so. I'll read up on delegates and events. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put a MyScreen property on the Player class.  When you create the Player class, set that property to your screen class.  You now have a reference to screen that you can call from inside player.

Answer (score 0):

Well, *something* in `Player` needs to have a reference to the `Screen` instance. Options:

- When you create the `Player`, pass `this` to the constructor so that it can remember the `Screen` it belongs to
- Create an event on `Player` and subscribe to it from `Screen`
- Pass the `Screen` along as parameters along the method call chain involved (this may not be practical in your situation)